# View Pager In React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, compiler-errors, android-viewpager

[image]

I am Trying Install React Native View Pager. But This Kind Of Error show When I run the app.
My code

```
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {PagerTabIndicator, IndicatorViewPager, PagerTitleIndicator, PagerDotIndicator} from 'rn-viewpager';

export default class ViewPagerPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <IndicatorViewPager
                style={{height:200}}
                indicator={this._renderDotIndicator()}
            >
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'cadetblue'}}>
                    <Text>page one</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'cornflowerblue'}}>
                    <Text>page two</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'#1AA094'}}>
                    <Text>page three</Text>
                </View>
            </IndicatorViewPager>

            <IndicatorViewPager
                style={{flex:1, paddingTop:20, backgroundColor:'white'}}
                indicator={this._renderTitleIndicator()}
            >
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'cadetblue'}}>
                    <Text>page one</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'cornflowerblue'}}>
                    <Text>page two</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'#1AA094'}}>
                    <Text>page three</Text>
                </View>
            </IndicatorViewPager>

            <IndicatorViewPager
                style={{flex:1, paddingTop:20, backgroundColor:'white'}}
                indicator={this._renderTabIndicator()}
            >
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'cadetblue'}}>
                    <Text>page one</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'cornflowerblue'}}>
                    <Text>page two</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'#1AA094'}}>
                    <Text>page three</Text>
                </View>
            </IndicatorViewPager>
        </View>
    );
}

_renderTitleIndicator() {
    return <PagerTitleIndicator titles={['one', 'two', 'three']} />;
}

_renderDotIndicator() {
    return <PagerDotIndicator pageCount={3} />;
}

_renderTabIndicator() {
    let tabs = [{
            text: 'Home',
            iconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_home_normal.png'),
            selectedIconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_home_click.png')
        },{
            text: 'Message',
            iconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_task_normal.png'),
            selectedIconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_task_click.png')
        },{
            text: 'Profile',
            iconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_my_normal.png'),
            selectedIconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_my_click.png')
    }];
    return <PagerTabIndicator tabs={tabs} />;
}
```

}

Comment: show your code here

Answer (score 1):

You should install new package with below command
`npm install --save @shankarmorwal/rn-viewpager`

and replace your below line from
`import {PagerTabIndicator, IndicatorViewPager, PagerTitleIndicator, PagerDotIndicator} from '@shankarmorwal/rn-viewpager';`

to

`import {PagerTabIndicator, IndicatorViewPager, PagerTitleIndicator, PagerDotIndicator} from '@shankarmorwal/rn-viewpager';`

Everything should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to install rn-viewpager just install it then run

```
yarn add rn-viewpager
react-native run-android
```

Comment: No I have installed  rn-viewpager

Comment: remove node_mosules and then re install